# Policy based authorization needs to return some reason when it fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, policy

First some code:

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IsLoggedIn", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserName);
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserID);
        });
        options.AddPolicy("IsCustomer", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserType, nameof(Customer));
        });
        options.AddPolicy("IsAdministrator", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserType, nameof(Administrator));
        });
        options.AddPolicy("IsApplication", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserType, nameof(Application));
        });
        options.AddPolicy("IsSystem", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserType, nameof(Application), nameof(Administrator));
        });
        options.AddPolicy("HasCart", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(StoreApi.Properties.Resources.UserCart);
        });
    });
```

I have a bunch of claim-base policies and the claims are defined in a resource while some need to have a specific value. These claims come from a JWT token and the whole thing is a simplified web store. And these policies work well, except for one issue...
When the user fails to meet a policy, they get a 403 "Forbidden" message, but no explanation about what's wrong. And because I have multiple policies, I would like to know which policy failed.
So, how do I make sure that the 403 provides this extra data to the client?

Comment: These are kept as vague as possible as to not give away any information to people with bad intentions. Unless you plan on only using this functionality in development or for server logging, I wouldn't recommend implementing this.

Comment: @Roe Good point, but these policies aren't providing that much information. Basically saying that you're not an admin or customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you should implement your own `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article.

Example:

Policy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesAuthorizationRequirement(new[] { "Admin" }));
            policy.Requirements.Add(new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("MyClaim", new[] { "Test" }));
        });
});
```

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() => Ok(true);
```

Custom `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler`

```
public class MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();

    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        // Fall back to the default implementation.
        await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);

        //Have to write to body after default implementation because is sets Http Code 
        if (!authorizeResult.Succeeded)
        {
            string? text = authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure?.FailedRequirements.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                (builder, reason) => builder.Append(reason + Environment.NewLine), builder => builder.ToString());
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        }
    }
}
```

Its registartion

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, 
                                MyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
```

After all these steps the result after calling endpoint would be response with status code 403:

```
RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (Admin)
ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement:Claim.Type=MyClaim and Claim.Value is one of the following values: (Test)
```

If you want to customize the response text you should work with `FailedRequirements` and `FailureReasons` properties of `authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure`.

Sources:

- [Customize the behavior of AuthorizationMiddleware - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationmiddlewareresulthandler)